# "python -i print_content.py < file.txt" exits interactive mode

Tags: python, bash, command-line, python-interactive

`python -i <script.py>` is theoretically meant to run `script.py` and proceed into interactive mode, however:

```
shell$ python -i print_content.py < file.txt
hello world

>>>
shell$
```

The script runs successfully and is followed by printing `>>>`, implying that the Python shell *is* entered following script execution.

I know I could bypass the issue by opening the file from within the script - I'm more curious to know the cause of the issue.

Note: Contents of print_content.py seem innocent enough:

```
import sys
for i in sys.stdin:
    print i
```

Note: I'm using Python 2.7.3

Comment: Interactive mode gets its input from stdin.

Comment: @Ryan Right, and wouldn't `< file.txt` be providing such input?

Comment: Your script reads `sys.stdin` to the end, and stdin reads from `file.txt`. Python runs the script, stdin is read, and there’s nothing left for the interactive session when it starts.

Comment: Thank you for the response!